# How do I automatically size a window?

Tags: vim-windows

I often program with lines no more than 80 characters long.  I start with an 80-character-wide terminal, but sometimes due to a plugin runs or after creating a vsplit results in the editing area being less than 80 characters wide.

For example, `:set number` will take four columns from the editing area and use them for line numbers.  After this, using `:vertical resize`, only changes the size relative to other splits, it doesn't widen the window.

Is there a way to keep the width of the editing area at a fixed width or to quickly resize the editing area or the window to a specified width?

Comment: `set columns=90` will resize a gvim, but unfortunately that's the total width, not the width of the displayed text. So you'd have to use 84+ with numbers on.

Comment: Are you talking about (internal) Vim-windows, or the Terminal itself, or both?

Comment: I'm talking about both. If the Vim window needs to be larger than the terminal width, I'd like the terminal to expand.  Perhaps this isn't possible within vim...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the various window functions. For example `ctrl-w =` will set all splits to equal width. There are also methods to set the window to a certain width, increase/decrease width by N, always maintain equal width, etc...
`:help window-resize`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+ `(n)` <kbd>></kbd>/<kbd><</kbd>: For right/left
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+ `(n)` <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>: For up/down
where n = any number.

Answer (score 1):

`:vertical resize 80` will set your current vsplit to 80 characters wide

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL-W` with pipe `|` will set the window to a specific width. E.g., to set the window to 80 columns/characters wide:

<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> + <kbd>80</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>

From `:help window-resize` (~ @collin-peters):

> Set current window width to N (default: widest possible)

Comment: I _think_ typically you'd type `80` C-w `|`, but if the other way around works, too, that's great.

Comment: Indeed, both work.